# using external config file for a .NET windows service

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, windows-services, app-config

I have an app.config file for a windows service which includes database connection strings and appsettings. when I install the windows service, it gets installed in "C:\program files\" folder and the settings are copied to a file called ".exe.config" in the same folder, which makes it difficult to change the settings after it is deployed to test environment. can I have all settings stored in an external file somewhere on shared network drive, instead of the same folder where the service is installed? is that possible? only alternative I can think of is to create an xml file and read it using the .NET XML API, another issue is I need to watch for the changes in the file and reload the settings in the service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771814/how-to-read-app-config-from-a-custom-location-i-e-from-a-database-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771814/how-to-read-app-config-from-a-custom-location-i-e-from-a-database-in-net).

Comment: You can always create your own XML config file and manage the settings from here.

Answer (score 2):

Linq to XML makes it fairly easy to read an external settings file. You can also use a FileSystemWatcher to watch for changes in the settings file.

Answer (score 2):

You can push some of your config settings out of your core config file, e.g.:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config" />
```

And:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connectionStrings>

</connectionString>
```

That way, as long as you don't deploy the `connectionStrings.config` file, you can safely deploy the app and maintain those settings separately.  The good thing about this approach, is you don't need to create a whole new method of getting config data, this is built into the configuration system, just read these settings how you do currently.